# I have a dv6 3122us laptop,and wondering what kind of upgrades i can get for games?

Tags: graphics-card, upgrade, amd-radeon, hp-pavilion

Everything stock.I have the 4gb ram,but didnt know if putting the 8gb ram will even help,or be used.Can i change the video card,or is it soldered?I already have the 2.4 ghz cpu,but can i put bigger processer?The reason i ask is minecraft,and tekkin needs to be played.I haven't tried yet.really just want to know whats the most i can get out this dv6.
How can I modify the setup so as to get better performance out of it? What are the parts that I can upgrade? It's more about what I *can* upgrade rather than asking for exact details of parts and so. Any recommendations would be welcome.

Comment: I know this question has been closed as off-topic, but as a tip that I have done and have suggested to people that can handle it is to install an easy to use Linux OS on the computer. Linux uses a lot less resources than Windows, therefor the graphics can be dialed up a few notches to make a better experience. I know someone who recently installed Linux Mint on their old laptop and now have Minecraft set to max graphics settings. They were at the worst settings with Windows Vista. Linux Mint is an easy to use, free OS that could accomplish the task. I don't know if Tekkin would be compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video card is usually soldered to the board. In case of laptops, IIRC you cannot upgrade the graphics once you buy it. I tried asking around for my Dell XPS, but was told that nothing can be done about the GPU. You could try upgrading your RAM, and check if you can safely overclock your existing GPU. Except RAM, there's nothing much to do here sadly. Just make sure you use the latest drivers, and keep your laptop on High performance power setting.

Comment: So if its soldered then why they have the glue around it?Do they really get so hot the solder will melt,and chip slide.

Comment: I can't say why they have glue around it, but one thing for sure, I do not know of anyone who would even attempt to change that.

Comment: upgrade.question